# on page load event $.ajax function sends ajax request. while we looks the url in the Global.asax file it is different Url

Tags: jquery, ajax, request

```
$(function () {

 $.ajax({
            url: "MySettings/ChangePassword",                
            type: "post",
            success: function (response) {
                $('#view-settings').html(response);
                hideFlyWithMessage("Loaded");
            }
        });
}
```

when the above code is executed it send request to `"MySettings/Index/MySettings/ChangePassWord"` url.

It clearly shows in console window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place **slash(/)** at beginning, then ajax url treat it as `hostname/yourURL`

So, change url as below

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/MySettings/ChangePassword",
.....
});
```